# bash cell magic runs but then spits out a long error

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Given the following `bash` cell magic:

```
> %%bash
! ls
```

The command runs - but then throws an exception:

```
Untitled.ipynb
contradictory-my-dear-watson.zip
sample_submission.csv
test.csv
train.csv
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9b04a68257be> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('bash', '', '! ls\n')

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2360             with self.builtin_trap:
   2361                 args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2362                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2363             return result
   2364 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in named_script_magic(line, cell)
    140             else:
    141                 line = script
--> 142             return self.shebang(line, cell)
    143 
    144         # write a basic docstring:

<decorator-gen-110> in shebang(self, line, cell)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/script.py in shebang(self, line, cell)
    243             sys.stderr.flush()
    244         if args.raise_error and p.returncode!=0:
--> 245             raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, cell, output=out, stderr=err)
    246 
    247     def _run_script(self, p, cell, to_close):

CalledProcessError: Command 'b'! ls\n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

What is the cause of the error and is there a fix/workaround?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: No. This is  clearlky a bug in the bash plugin

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
I am not sure if it is the same problem.
However I give my solution.

My situation: I installed the bash_kernel with Conda and used it in a Jupyter Notebook environment. Despite, cell magic "%%bash" did not work."!" works. Whatever! Normally it is not recommended to use cell magic and line magic together. However my problem was that cell magic did not work.

Turns out even in Jupyter it is a Windows/Linux problem.
I am using Windows. Solution is to use Linux Bash in Windows.

It works then if the Jupyter notebook is started from Git Bash in my case. An alternative is to install Ubuntu under Windows and run it from Ubuntu Bash. This works too. However you have to connect the Git Bash to Anaconda. This is explained here:

"In your GitBash prompt type the following command
. Anaconda3/Scripts/activate
assuming you are in your home directory. This will allow you to run jupyter from GitBash and also use UNIX commands from jupyter."
[Find here][1]